# Performance issue with ASP.NET / IIS on a VM against Azure SQL

Tags: asp.net, performance, azure, iis, azure-sql-database

I know this is a bit of a broad question, but please bear with me.

We have a standard Azure Windows VM with IIS and ASP.NET Webservices. All DB queries are run against Azure SQL.
We have a page that makes about 18 REST calls at the same time and all those REST calls internally query the Azure SQL DB.

This is how it looks locally:
[image]

And against our live server:
[image]

So on the live server, Chrome is obviously limiting the amount of connection to 6.
After a quick glance, it just looks like the first few queries are very slow. They indeed take a little time, but never 5sec or more if you run them individually. Maybe 0.5sec at most.
Ok, so 2nd idea, IIS or SQL server is at the performance limit if I run all these calls at the same time. 
But if I run any of the six calls individually from Postman at the same time as waiting for the website to load, they return in sub-second time. So it can't be the IIS or the SQL server that is at peak. It seems like these calls kinda block each other if they are from the same source or something.

Is there anything common in my setup that could cause this slowdown when I fire multiple calls from one client?

The SQL calls are just simple "Selects", no updates or something.

Comment: Are VM and Azure SQL located in same region?

Comment: Yes. The REST call in itself if posted separately by Postman (but at the same time as all the other requests run) is fast.

Comment: Have you look at resource consumption on Azure SQL Database?

Comment: What's your telemetry saying? Where's the time being spent? Application Insights has a nice .NET profiler under its "Performance" blade. Also those ajax calls look suspiciously sequential, are you sure they fire in parallel?